# If the bitcoin address changes every time, why there is more than one transaction for an address in the ledger?

Tags: transactions, address, address-generation, address-reuse, blockchain-explorer

I was checking a random address in blockchain.com, there are alot of transactions that is done over this address. While in the website it is mentioned that the address is changing everytime! So it means that every address should hold at most one transaction!

Comment: There is no such thing as a Bitcoin address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to differentiate between the website's wallet (Blockchain.info-wallet) and the blockchain itself.

You are allowed (by the bitcoin protocol) to make as many transactions per adress as you want.

But wallets try to make it as comfortable as possible for you and use one adress only one time so that you are acting as pseudonymously as possible.

You have probably seen an adress that has not been handled within such a "only one time"-wallet.

Comment: Even if no reuse took place, you'd still see 2 transactions (one that creates an output assigned to that address, and one that spends that output).

Comment: I didn't get your point about the differences between wallet and blockchain!? A transaction inside a blockchain is from a bitcoin address (wallet) to another one. isn't it? So my question is if after a transaction, the address is changing, then I should not have more than a transaction with one address while it is not like this in the ledger.

Comment: No, an adress is not a wallet. A transaction is from one or more adress(es) to one or more adress(es). A wallet is only a nice tool to handle/store all your adresses and private keys and it tells you your balance... You don't even need such a wallet to send or receive bitcoins. It's your choice / the choice of your wallet provider to use an adress only one time or multiple times.

Comment: The blockchain.info-wallet maybe allows you to use an adress only one time because they think, it's more secure. But the decentralized blockchain accepts any number of transactions from one adress.

Comment: @Rahas: "in the website it is mentioned that the address is changing everytime" Indeed blockchain.info is just one website; it is not "the blockchain" nor does it have any official status with respect to Bitcoin. So while it may be blockchain.info's practice with respect to its users' wallets to issue a new address for each transaction, it is not the practice of every wallet to do that. Some wallets issue a new address only when the user requests a new address. Regardless, anyone is free to give any one receiving address to multiple senders.

Comment: @Alpha Thanks for the explanation. I got it. :)